# Trying to/How To post an Image file from Angular front end to .NET CORE Backend API --

Tags: angular, image, http, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to know what is the best way to do this.

From my Angular 8 app, I am selecting an img file and would like to send this image file to a .NET Core API backend. The backend service should save this img in
the database.

html for my image selector -

```
<div class="image-picker" (click)="fileInput.click()">
  <mat-icon [class.small]="imageUrl">file_upload</mat-icon>
  <canvas width="500" height="380" #canvas hidden="true"></canvas>
  <input #fileInput type="file" hidden="true" (change)="imageDataChanged($event)">
</div>
```

respective .ts code -

```
imageDataChanged($event) {
    var file = $event.target.files[0];


    console.log(file);

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // get data from file input and emit as dataUrl
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      var ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
      this.imageUrl = reader.result;
      this.imagePicked.emit(this.imageUrl);
    }, false);

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```

So I get in my console, details related to the file I selected. Like name, size, date, datemodified ..... Upon clicking a submit button I'd like to post this file to the backend API. My question is - in what format and how. base64 image? What's the code for that. How would I do that. Like I said, my backend is in .NET Core.

Here's the code I attempted -

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("CaptureSaveImg")]
        public IActionResult CaptureSaveImg(HttpContext context)
        {
            string imageName = null;
            var httpRequest = context.Request;

            var postedFile = httpRequest.Form.Files["Image"];

            try
            {
                if(postedFile!=null)
                {
                    var fileName = postedFile.FileName;

                    var myUniqueFileName = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());

                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

                    var newFileName = string.Concat(myUniqueFileName, fileExtension);

                    var filepath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "CameraPics") + $@"\{newFileName}";

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
                    {
                        // Storing Image in Folder  
                        StoreInFolder(postedFile, filepath);
                    }

                    var imageBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
                    if (imageBytes != null)
                    {
                        StoreInDatabase(imageBytes);
                    }

                    return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "Image Saved." });
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "An error occurred while saving the image." });
                }
            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {
                return Json(new { Success =false, Message="An unexpected error occurred!"});
            }
        }


private void StoreInDatabase(byte[] imageBytes)
        {
            try
            {
                if (imageBytes != null)
                {
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                    string imageUrl = string.Concat("data:image/jpg;base64,", base64String);
                    ImageStore imageStore = new ImageStore()
                    {
                        CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                        ImageBase64String = imageUrl,
                        ImageId = 0
                    };
                    _context.ImageStores.Add(imageStore);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                throw exp.InnerException;
            }
        }

        private void StoreInFolder(IFormFile file, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(fs);
                    fs.Flush();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                throw exp.InnerException;
            }

        }
```

html for button click -

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="button" (click)="OnSubmit(Image)" >UPLOAD</button>
```

.ts for button click -

```
OnSubmit(file: File)
  {
    this.userRestService.uploadImage(this.fileToUpload)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log('Done successfully! '+data.Message);
        this.imageUrl = null;
      });
  }
```

In the use-rest service -

```
fileToUpload: File = null;  

uploadImage(file: File) {
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'No-Auth': 'True' });

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Image', file, file.name);

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl +'CaptureSaveImg', formData, { headers: reqHeader });
  }
```

I want to first save it in a local folder path and then from there, read the file and save in DB. I do9 understand that when I am trying to post it as
fileToUpload, it is sending null probably.

Problem I am facing - what do I post/send from the front end to the API. How. Can you show me some code that would achive this. Can you give me a step by step guide to achieve this.

Feel free to ask for more details on what I attempted, to gain better insight.
Thanks

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention earlier that my image picker component is basically a separate angular component that I am using as  in my main page. So the imageDataChanged($event) code is also in that component. Let me post.

```
<input #fileInput type="file" hidden="true" (change)="imageDataChanged($event)">
```

The .ts code -

```
imageDataChanged($event) {
    var file = $event.target.files[0];
    this.ds.selectedFile = file;

    if (file.length===0) {
      return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // get data from file input and emit as dataUrl
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      var ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
      this.imageUrl = reader.result;
      this.imagePicked.emit(this.imageUrl);
    }, false);

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append(file.name, file);

    this.ds.formDataPost = formData;

  }
```

Here ds is nothing but an intermediate data sharing injectable class.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataSharingService {

  public selectedFile: any;

  public formDataPost: any;

}
```

Now, my OnSubmit code -

```
OnSubmit()
  {
    console.log(this.ds.formDataPost);

    const uplRequest = new HttpRequest('POST', this.baseUrl + '/CaptureSaveImg', this.ds.formDataPost, { reportProgress: true });

    this.http.request(uplRequest)
      .subscribe((data: any) =>
      {
        if (data.Success == "true")
        {
          console.log("Upload successful.");
        }
        else
        {
          console.log("Problem while uploading file.");
        }
      })
  }
```

I'm just getting error - ***core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.***

I think I am close. Any conversion needed? Or format of data?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by saving to the database as Base 64. This is convenient because after you convert the image immediately on the client to a string, posting to the server and saving to the database is trivial.

```js
myForm = new FormGroup({
  foo: new FormControl(''), // etc...
  imageBase64: new FormControl('')
});

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

onImageAttached(event): void {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
    const [file] = event.target.files;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.onload = () => {
      this.myForm.patchValue({
        imageBase64: reader.result
      });

      // need to run CD since file load runs outside of zone
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    };
  }
}
```

Later if you are displaying these images within the app, you can send that base64 string all the way to the DOM.

On the other hand, if you've got a web server rendering your Angular client, you could also convert to a file on the server for performance reasons. That gives you an app route for your images.

```cs
public class AppImageController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
    {
        var imageBase64 = await _imageRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);

        var mimeStartIndex = imageBase64.IndexOf("image/");

        var mime = imageBase64
            .Substring(
                mimeStartIndex,
                result.Data.Attachment.IndexOf(';') - mimeStartIndex
             );

        var content = imageBase64
            .Remove(0, result.Data.Attachment.LastIndexOf(',') + 1);

        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);

        return File(bytes, mime.Length > 0 ? mime : "image/png");
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="AppImage/Index/{{appImage.id}}"
     alt="{{appImage.name}}">
```

This isn't to say saving images to the database is always the best call. Saving to a server file system, AWS S3 file store, etc. are all very viable options. There are trade-offs between these approaches that you can research.

Comment: hi @AdamDunkerley thanks for the reply - let me read through this approach you posted. and try out at my end. I'll revert with any progress/trouble I face; As for the saving to DB portion, yes, I am just keeping it as an additional ensuring measure aside from saving the image in my local folder structure.  Let me try to incorporate the code you suggested,

Comment: hi @AdamDunkerley - I updated my code in main answer. Pl take a look. There's 1 error now,

Comment: Can you specify when that error occurs? Do you know what part of the code is causing it? You'll probably want to set some console logs so that you can find what argument is undefinded.

Comment: well, it occurs when I click the button to submit the image to API. In fact, I set my button type to "button" instead of "submit" to avoid unnecessary nuisance. Let me try and get some console logs,    I'll post them,    @AdamDunkerley